# Custom post query by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I am using WordPress 3.5. My query is,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'comic', 'magazine'),
    'taxonomy' => 'Genres',
    'term' => 'hot',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

// Restore original Query & Post Data
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This gives the exact result that I want but,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'comic', 'magazine'),
    'taxonomy' => 'Genres',
    'term' => array('hot','home'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

// Restore original Query & Post Data
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This is not working.

Comment: Did you try 'tax_query' http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

I'm slightly surprised that the first would work, because it's `terms`, not `term`. Anyway, [the correct way](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to do this is:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'comic', 'magazine'),
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Genres',
        'terms'    => array( 'hot', 'home' ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
```